# Linq to objects is 20 times slower than plain C#. Is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

If I need just the maximum [or the 3 biggest items] of an array, and I do it with myArray.OrderBy(...).First() [or myArray.OrderBy(...).Take(3)], it is 20 times slower than calling myArray.Max(). Is there a way to write a faster linq query? This is my sample:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = new int[1000000];
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = i;
            }

            var maxResults = new int[10];
            var linqResults = new int[10];
            var start = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxResults.Length; i++)
            {
                maxResults[i] = array.Max();
            }
            var maxEnd = DateTime.Now;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxResults.Length; i++)
            {
                linqResults[i] = array.OrderByDescending(it => it).First();
            }
            var linqEnd = DateTime.Now;

            // 00:00:00.0748281
            // 00:00:01.5321276
            Console.WriteLine(maxEnd - start);
            Console.WriteLine(linqEnd - maxEnd);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var linqResults = array.OrderByDescending(it => it).Take(10).ToArray();`

Comment: Getting the max is O(n), while sorting is probably O(n log(n)). Ergo, don't sort to get the max.

Comment: Why do you think you are not using Linq when it is array.Max(). You are using Linq in both, just doing one of them in a much longer way.

Comment: Please read the Speed Rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Linq-to-Sql is I suppose optimized to don't sort the entire table and then take just 1 item from it. That's why I thought that Linq-to-objects is smart enough to don't sort the entire array.

Comment: Your title is misleading as it's not just LINQ that is slower, you've picked a completely different thing to do. The act of just iterating through the collection once, collecting the highest value along the way, is orders of magnitude faster than having to sort the entire collection and then grab one value from one end.

Comment: In a database, if your regular data access pattern included getting the three biggest items, then I'd hope you'd have an index on that column. At that point, the optimizer could figure out a fast path to the solution. <rant>There are a lot of folks who think that a LINQ solution is always the best one</rant>. As several people has pointed out,  getting the Max(N) from a collection is an O(N) operation in a very simple loop.

Answer (score 1):

You sort the initial array `10` times in a loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < maxResults.Length; i++)
    {
        linqResults[i] = array.OrderByDescending(it => it).First();
    }
```

Let's do it *once*:

```
    // 10 top item of the array
    var linqResults = array
      .OrderByDescending(it => it)
      .Take(10)
      .ToArray();
```

please, note, that

```
    for (int i = 0; i < maxResults.Length; i++)
    {
         maxResults[i] = array.Max();
    }
```

just repeat the *same* `Max` value `10` times (it doesn't return `10` top items)

Comment: Still, getting the max 10 can be done in O(n). Guess the challenge is the linq requirement.

Comment: I've done it 10 times just to measure the time more accurately. I want to do it just once.

Comment: Technically, we can do it in O(N), e.g. we can use `Min Heap`: we loop over `array`, while adding item to the heap; when size of it reaches `11` we take (and throw away) the top (min) item from the heap.

Comment: There is no built in MinHeap (or  PriorityQueue) either in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

Max method time consumption is O(n) and Ordering in the best time is O(n log(n))
First error of your code is that you are ordering 10 times which is worst scenario. You can order one time and take 10 of them like what Dmitry answered.
And also, calling Max method for 10 times does not give you 10 biggest values, just the biggest value for 10 times.

However Max method does iterating list once and keep the Max value in a seperate variable. You can rewrite this method to iterate you array and keep you 10 biggest values in your maxResults and this is the fastest way that you can get result.

Comment: Its impressive how many people are talking besides the subject. I called it 10 times just to measure the time more accurately. What I was looking for, but in linq, is in my answer (morelinq).

Comment: So, your answer is time consumption of methods Max and OrderBy. Max algorithm time is O(n) and Ordering time is O( n log n). There is no way to use OrderBy or OrderByDescending in a faster way of Max method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that others have filled the efficiency gap that Microsoft has left in linq-to-objects:
https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_PartialSort__1_3.htm